# DHCP for a local network lab instrument

Tags: switch, router, dhcp

**Set up:** I have a closed network consisting of a switch, a PC (with 2 NICs), [instrument](https://www.rohde-schwarz.com/vn/product/sgs100a-productstartpage_63493-9030.html) and a [router](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/unified-communications/small-business-voice-gateways-ata/datasheet_C78-691107.html). The PCs primary card, instrument and the router are all connected to the switch. The secondary network card on the pc is connected to the internet.

**Problem:** I need DHCP for the instrument so I am trying to figure out how to set up the router so that it manages IP addresses in this closed network. The instrument has to be able to communicate with the PC to run experiments. I am not sure if the router I have is sufficient for this task.

Would like to have some tips on how to go about this problem because I am new with networking.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Cisco SPA112 ATA with router" provides a DHCP server.

From [this guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/csbpvga/spa100-200/admin_guide_SPA100/spa100_ag/new_network_setup.html)

> **Network Settings for the LAN and DHCP Server (SPA122 Only)**
>
> Use the Network Setup > Basic Setup > Network Settings page to set the
>   IP address and subnet mask for your local network. Also configure the
>   settings for the built-in DHCP server (SPA122 only).
>
> Enter the settings as described below. After making changes, click
>   Submit to save your settings, or click Cancel to redisplay the page
>   with the saved settings.
>
> **Router IP**
>
> Enter the Local IP Address and Subnet Mask for your local network. The
>   default setting is 192.168.15.1 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0.
>
> DHCP Server Setting
>
> Field    Description
>
> **DHCP Server**
>
> The ATA can use the built-in DHCP server to dynamically assign IP
>   addresses to connected devices. Click Enabled to enable the DHCP
>   server, or click Disabled to disable this feature. Default setting:
>   Enabled
>
> **IP Reservation:**
>
> Click the Show DHCP Reservation button to view and manage the DHCP
>   client list. Click the Hide DHCP Reservation button to hide the list.
>   When the list is displayed, you can perform the following tasks:
>
> ```
> To reserve a static IP address for a current DHCP client: Check the box for the client in the Select Clients from DHCP Tables list.
> ```
>
> Click Add Clients. The selected clients are added to the Clients
>   Already Reserved list. These clients have static IP addresses that do
>   not change.
>       To add a client that is not in the Select Clients from DHCP Tables list: Type a name for the client in the Enter Client Name box. Enter
>   an IP address for this client in the Assign IP Address box. Enter the
>   MAC address in the following format: 00:00:00:00:00:00. Click Add.
>       To remove a client from the Clients Already Reserved list: Check the box for the client. Click Remove.
>
> **Default Gateway**
>
> Enter the IP address of the default gateway to be used by the DHCP
>   clients. Default setting: 192.168.15.1 (the IP address of the ETHERNET
>   (LAN) interface)
>
> **Starting IP Address**
>
> Enter the first address in the range of addresses to be assigned
>   dynamically by the DHCP server. Default setting: 192.168.15.100
>
> **Maximum DHCP Users**
>
> Enter the maximum number of devices that can dynamically receive, or
>   “lease,” DHCP addresses from the DHCP server. Default setting: 50
>
> IMPORTANT: Typically, the ATA can support up to five connected
>   computers for business-related tasks such as web browsing and viewing
>   email. The ATA is not designed to support streaming music, video,
>   games, or other network traffic-intensive tasks.
>
> **Client Lease Time**
>
> Enter the number of minutes that a dynamically assigned IP address can
>   be in use, or “leased.” After this time elapses, a client device has
>   to request a DHCP lease renewal. Use 0 to represent 1 day, 9999 never
>   expire. Default setting: 0
>
> **Option 66**
>
> Provides provisioning server address information to hosts that request
>   this option. Server information can be defined in one of three ways:
>
> ```
> None: The ATA uses its own TFTP server to source provisioning files, so it returns its own local IP address to the client.
> Remote TFTP Server: The ATA was configured by using this method, and received server information through Option 66 on its WAN
> ```
>
> interface. In response to client requests, it provides the remote TFTP
>   server information.
>       Manual TFTP Server: Allows the manual configuration of a configuration server address. While this option is typically used to
>   provide either an IP address or a fully qualified hostname, the ATA
>   will also accept and offer a full URL including protocol, path and
>   filename to meet to requirements of specific clients.
>
> Default setting: None
>
> **TFTP Server**
>
> If you chose Manual TFTP Server for Option 66, enter the IP address,
>   hostname, or URL of the TFTP server that is used to configure the ATA.
>   Default setting: blank
>
> **Option 67**
>
> Provides a configuration/bootstrap filename to hosts that request this
>   option. This option is used in conjunction with option 66 to allow a
>   client to form an appropriate TFTP request for the file. Default
>   setting: blank
>
> **Option 159**
>
> Provides a configuration URL to clients that request this option. An
>   option 159 URL defines the protocol and path information by using an
>   IP address for clients that cannot use DNS. For example:
>   https://10.1.1.1:888/configs/bootstrap.cfg Default setting: blank
>
> **Option 160**
>
> Provides a configuration URL to clients that request this option. An
>   option 160 URL defines the protocol and path information by using a
>   fully qualified domain name for clients that can use DNS. For example:
>   https://myconfigs.cisco.com:888/configs/bootstrap.cfg Default setting:
>   blank
>
> **DNS Proxy**
>
> When enabled, the DNS proxy relays DNS requests to the current public
>   network DNS server for the proxy, and replies as a DNS resolver to the
>   client device on the network. Click Enabled to enable this feature, or
>   click Disabled to disable it. If DNS proxy is disabled, then DHCP
>   clients will be offered DNS server information by using the Static DNS
>   servers, if defined, or by using the using the servers specified for
>   the INTERNET (WAN) interface. Default setting: Enabled

Comment: Thanks! Finally figured it out and the instrument gets assigned a nice IP address by the router. Didn't think it will be this easy!